# How to test http calls in Go using httptest

Tags: http, go

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type twitterResult struct {
    Results []struct {
        Text     string `json:"text"`
        Ids      string `json:"id_str"`
        Name     string `json:"from_user_name"`
        Username string `json:"from_user"`
        UserId   string `json:"from_user_id_str"`
    }
}

var (
  twitterUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23UCL"
  pauseDuration = 5 * time.Second
)

func retrieveTweets(c chan<- *twitterResult) {
    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(twitterUrl)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        r := new(twitterResult) //or &twitterResult{} which returns *twitterResult
        err = json.Unmarshal(body, &r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        c <- r
        time.Sleep(pauseDuration)
    }

}

func displayTweets(c chan *twitterResult) {
    tweets := <-c
    for _, v := range tweets.Results {
        fmt.Printf("%v:%v\n", v.Username, v.Text)
    }

}

func main() {
    c := make(chan *twitterResult)
    go retrieveTweets(c)
    for {
        displayTweets(c)
    }

}
```

I'd like to write some tests for it, but I'm not sure how to use the httptest package http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/ would appreciate some pointers

I came up with this (shamelessly copied from the tests for go OAuth https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/oauth/oauth_test.go):

```
var request = struct {
    path, query       string // request
    contenttype, body string // response
}{
    path:        "/search.json?",
    query:       "q=%23Kenya",
    contenttype: "application/json",
    body:        twitterResponse,
}

var (
    twitterResponse = `{ 'results': [{'text':'hello','id_str':'34455w4','from_user_name':'bob','from_user_id_str':'345424'}]}`
)

func TestRetrieveTweets(t *testing.T) {
    handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", request.contenttype)
        io.WriteString(w, request.body)
    }

    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(handler))
    defer server.Close()

    resp, err := http.Get(server.URL)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Get: %v", err)
    }
    checkBody(t, resp, twitterResponse)
}

func checkBody(t *testing.T, r *http.Response, body string) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("reading reponse body: %v, want %q", err, body)
    }
    if g, w := string(b), body; g != w {
        t.Errorf("request body mismatch: got %q, want %q", g, w)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 97):

httptest does two types of tests: response and server

Response test:

```
func TestHeader3D(t *testing.T) {
    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()

    uri := "/3D/header/?"
    path := "/home/test"
    unlno := "997225821"

    param := make(url.Values)
    param["param1"] = []string{path}
    param["param2"] = []string{unlno}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", uri+param.Encode(), nil)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }

    http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
    if p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err != nil {
            t.Fail()
    } else {
            if strings.Contains(string(p), "Error") {
                    t.Errorf("header response shouldn't return error: %s", p)
            } else if !strings.Contains(string(p), `expected result`) {
                    t.Errorf("header response doen't match:\n%s", p)
            }
    }
}
```

Server test (which is what you need to use):

```
func TestIt(t *testing.T){
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, `{"fake twitter json string"}`)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    twitterUrl = ts.URL
    c := make(chan *twitterResult)
    go retrieveTweets(c)

    tweet := <-c
    if tweet != expected1 {
        t.Fail()
    }
    tweet = <-c
    if tweet != expected2 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

BTW, you don't need to pass in the pointer of r, because it's already a pointer.

```
err = json.Unmarshal(body, r)
```

EDIT: for my recorder test, I could use my http handler like this:

```
handler(resp, req)
```

But my original code is not using the default mux (but from Gorilla/mux), and I have some wrapping around the mux, e.g. insert server logging, and adding request context (Gorilla/context), so I had to start from mux and call ServeHTTP

Comment: Please, add complete code, like importing all packages. Newbie here ;) Thanks!

Comment: You could use goimports

Answer (score 9):

Originally [this code snippet was found on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/cespare/4992458#file-myserver_test-go), but while trying to apply the concept to one of my projects I realized that I had to modify the main code significantly that I decided to test these calls using an integration test by using docker and curl.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to test your program, it is often best to write it with testing in mind.  For instance, if you extracted the inner loop of your `retrieveTweets` function into something like this:

```
func downloadTweets(tweetsUrl string) (*twitterResult, error)
```

You could invoke it with the URL of a test server you've set up using the `httptest` package without having to worry about the sleeps or repeated requests.

Comment: Can I mock out a server? I think wetting up a test server negates the purpose of the test, if I can mock out a server and the response I'm expecting that would fit in well with the test

Comment: The `httptest` package is the infrastructure to set up a small HTTP server for the tests.  You can implement the request handlers the same way you would normally, and then run your code against that server rather than Twitter.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge thank you, great answer! You comment here is more informative than the Overview Statement on the official docs for net/http/httptest

Comment: In this case, would `httptest` test response or server?